# why has firebug greyed-out my area element

Tags: html, firefox, firebug, area

```
<map name="theMap">
  <area alt="Find out more" style="cursor:pointer;" coords="0,0,10,10" shape="rect" href="#">
</map>
```

in firebug the area element is greyed out. There are no CSS styles affecting it. The map element shows clearly.

Comment: What doctype are you using? If XHTML, you need to close your tag <area />

Comment: I have. the above was the result of a copy from firebug. It has taken it out. I believe I may have found the answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I hadnt put a hash in the usemap attribute of my image.

`usemap="theMap"` should have been `usemap="#theMap"`

Comment: I believe other cases may be where an ad-blocker has removed the element.